# Replace Wordpress Specific Page Content Completely and Filter New Content Using the_content

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to replace the content on one of my Wordpress pages completely with new content. But I need to run that new content through the the_content filter to process shortcodes and add paragraphs, etc.

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
if($page_id==141 && is_main_query() ){
    $content = '<h3>Hi Mom!</h3>';
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
}
return $content;
```

}

I am putting this in my theme's child functions.php and that apply_filters line blows it up.

For a little more background on what I am doing I have two Wordpress websites on the same server and wish to have certain pages duplicated on both sites. So, on site #2, for a certain page, I am grabbing the post_content from the related page in the database of site #1 and then replacing the content in the second site page with this content. I'm able to get it working except for the part where I apply the Wordpress filter to process shortcodes and add paragraphs.

To try and further explain my convoluted task.

- Wordpress site #1 has a page that contains content that will be edited from time to time
- Wordpress site #2 has a similar page and I want to use the exact same content from site #1 in site #2 for this page (so I don't have to edit both pages every time one is updated)
- so my strategy has been to simply grab the content I want directly from the site #1 database and then use it instead of whatever content is already in the page (usually nothing) on site #2

I hope this makes sense! Thanks in advance for any assistance!!